# Polygons not animating CSS & JS(GSAP)

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I want to create a entry transition to my website but the polygons are not rendering like they should. The polygons animate on entry from right to left like window bind. It was working before with 10 Masks but I thought 20 would look better.

I tried adding `%` to 0s but no luck

The polygon values sometimes change style, sometimes not

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ishaan161028/pen/bGZpbwm)

[image]
[image]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");
  const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
  const elementsToAnimate = document.querySelectorAll(
    "p:not(.intro), .logo h1"
  );
  const introTag = document.querySelector(".intro");
  let animationIntialized = false;

  function shuffleText(finalText, duration, callback) {
    let i = 0;
    const shuffleInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (i < duration) {
        counter.innerHTML = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 8);
        i++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(shuffleInterval);
        counter.innerHTML = finalText;
        if (callback) callback();
      }
    }, 100)
  }


  function removeLetters() {
    let text = counter.innerHTML;
    const removeInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (text.length > 0) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        counter.innerHTML = text;
      } else {
        clearInterval(removeInterval);

        if (!animationIntialized) {
          animateElements();
          animateIntroTag();
        }
        fadeOutLoader();
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  function animateElements() {
    if (animationIntialized) return;
    animationIntialized = true;

    elementsToAnimate.forEach((element) => {
      let originalText = element.textContent;
      let index = 0;

      const shuffleElement = setInterval(() => {
        if (index < originalText.length) {
          let shuffledText = "";
          for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            shuffledText +=
              i < index ? originalText[i] : Math.random().toString(36)[2];
          }
          element.textContent =
            shuffledText + originalText.substring(index + 1);
          index++;
        } else {
          clearInterval(shuffleElement);
          element.textContent = originalText;
        }
      }, 100);
    });
  }

  function animateIntroTag() {
    let originalText = introTag.textContent;
    let currentText = "";
    let index = 0;

    const revealText = setInterval(() => {
      if (index < originalText.length) {
        currentText += originalText[index];
        introTag.textContent = currentText;
        index++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(revealText);
      }
    }, 25);
  }

  function animateMasks() {
    const masks = document.querySelectorAll(".hero-img .mask");
    const clipPathValues = [
      "clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5% 0%, 5% 100%, 0% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(5% 0%, 10% 0%, 10% 100%, 5% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 15% 0%, 15% 100%, 10% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(15% 0%, 20% 0%, 20% 100%, 15% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 25% 0%, 25% 100%, 20% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 30% 0%, 30% 100%, 25% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 35% 0%, 35% 100%, 30% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(35% 0%, 40% 0%, 40% 100%, 35% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(40% 0%, 45% 0%, 45% 100%, 40% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(45% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, 45% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 55% 0%, 55% 100%, 50% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(55% 0%, 60% 0%, 60% 100%, 55% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(60% 0%, 65% 0%, 65% 100%, 60% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(65% 0%, 70% 0%, 70% 100%, 65% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(70% 0%, 75% 0%, 75% 100%, 70% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 80% 0%, 80% 100%, 75% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(80% 0%, 85% 0%, 85% 100%, 80% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(85% 0%, 90% 0%, 90% 100%, 85% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(90% 0%, 95% 0%, 95% 100%, 90% 100%)",
      "clip-path: polygon(95% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 95% 100%)",
    ];

    setTimeout(() => {
      masks.forEach((mask, index) => {
        gsap.to(mask, {
          clipPath: clipPathValues[index % clipPathValues.length],
          duration: 1,
          delay: index * 0.1,
        });
      });
    });
  }

  gsap.to(counter, {
    innerHTML: 100 + "%",
    duration: 2.5,
    snap: "innerHTML",
    ease: "none",
    onComplete: () => {
      setTimeout(
        () =>
        shuffleText("ISAN/24", 5, () => {
          setTimeout(removeLetters, 800);
        }),
        800
      );
    },
  });

  function fadeOutLoader() {
    gsap.to(loader, {
      opacity: 0,
      pointerEvents: "none",
      duration: 1,
      onComplete: () => {
        animateMasks();
      },
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.hero-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3.9464882943144%;
  top: 37.68538874%;
  width: 51vw;
  height: 28.95vh;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 51vw;
  height: 28.95vh;
  background: url(assets/images/image.avif);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mask:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 5% 0%, 5% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 10% 0, 10% 100%, 5% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 15% 0, 15% 100%, 10% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 20% 0, 20% 100%, 15% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 25% 0, 25% 100%, 20% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(6) {
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 30% 0, 30% 100%, 25% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(7) {
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 35% 0, 35% 100%, 30% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(8) {
  clip-path: polygon(35% 0, 40% 0, 40% 100%, 35% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(9) {
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 45% 0, 45% 100%, 40% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(10) {
  clip-path: polygon(45% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 45% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(11) {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 55% 0, 55% 100%, 50% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(12) {
  clip-path: polygon(55% 0, 60% 0, 60% 100%, 55% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(13) {
  clip-path: polygon(60% 0, 65% 0, 65% 100%, 60% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(14) {
  clip-path: polygon(65% 0, 70% 0, 70% 100%, 65% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(15) {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 75% 0, 75% 100%, 70% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(16) {
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 80% 0, 80% 100%, 75% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(17) {
  clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 85% 0, 85% 100%, 80% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(18) {
  clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 90% 0, 90% 100%, 85% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(19) {
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0%, 95% 0%, 95% 100%, 90% 100%);
}

.mask:nth-child(20) {
  clip-path: polygon(95% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 95% 100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="project-link" draggable="false">
  <div class="hero-img">
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
  </div>
</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only hope to be helpful and I am wondering why pure css animation (webkit  keyframes) is not your preferred method for animating html elements? I believe you are missing a comma in this line:

const masks = document.querySelectorAll(".hero-img .mask"); - The classes must be separated by a comma - (".hero-img, .mask")

Comment: If you think there's only a `,` missing in the code, such answers should be closes for reason *`Typo`*. No need to provide answers. Since you cannot still provide comments, gain first the needed rep to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed just remove "clip-path:" prefix from JavaScript it will work fine